# Python 2.7 won't run in command line, yes I added to path variable

Tags: python, windows

Can't figure this out. I have followed the tutorials I have found to a T and it still won't run from cmd. I tried uploading a screenshot to show that C:\Python27 is in the Path env variable but I can't because I am a new user. Windows 7. See 'python' is not recognized as an internal...

```
C:\Users\paleus>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\paleus>set PATH
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin64;C:\PROG
RA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin\X11;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\mksnt;C:\IBM
\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\classic;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode
\lib\cpp;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MT_dll\bin;C:\Wind
ows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowe
rShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem";C:\Program Files\Tortois
eSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Python27\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.sh;.ksh;.csh;.sed
;.awk;.pl

C:\Users\paleus>
```

Comment: What is the command you type, and what is the result you see?

Comment: did you restart the command prompt after changing PATH? Do `echo %PATH%` in the command prompt and make sure the changes took (copy the results here for us). Also what happens if you do `C:\Python27\python`? Do you get the interactive shell?

Comment: Is the python executable in c:\Python27? or in c:\Python27\bin? I don't have a windows install, so I'm only guessing.

Comment: `'python' is not recognized as an internal` error comes only if the environment variable is not set properly or try restarting your cmd.

Comment: @pcalcao just checked my Windows install, python.exe is in C:\Python27 directly, not bin.

Comment: Yes it shows up when I do echo %PATH% or set PATH. I have restarted and tried C:\Python27\python.

Comment: @user1774774 can you paste the results of `echo %PATH%` here?

Comment: Is ".EXE" in your PATHEXT env variable?

Comment: There is a suspicious unmatched double-quote in your PATH after QTSystem, try removing it.

Comment: That double quote doesn't show up when I go to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is an unmatched double quote in your PATH variable for the following entry (fourth from the end):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem"
                                         ^
```

Comment: It's not there in the system properties edit system variable box. C:\Program Files ...IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\lib\cpp;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MT_dll\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem";C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Python27\

Comment: Ah, I see that there is 2.

Comment: @user1774774 The double quote appears in your comment as well.  It is fairly common to see entries with spaces surrounded by double quotes, but this isn't actually necessary (although it doesn't hurt either).

Comment: That was it. Thanks everyone. Not sure how that got in there.